# How to assign key and values to a dictionary from another dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am trying to assign key and values for a dictionary based on another dictionary as below,am not clear how to do it in C#,I have written the pseudo code for it below?can anyone help on how to do it in C#?

Class:

```
public class BuildMetrics
{
    public Dictionary<string, string[]> BitSanity { get; set; }
}
```

Code:-

```
var metrics = new BuildMetrics();
Dictionary<int, int[]> bitSanityResults = new Dictionary<int,int[]>(); 

try
{
    bitSanityResults = bitDB.bit_sanity_results.Where(x => x.software_product_build_id == latestBuildProductBuildId)
                            .ToDictionary(x => x.test_suite_id, x => 
                             new int[] { x.pass_count, x.fail_count });
}
catch(System.ArgumentException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
//pseudocode
foreach (var item in bitSanityResults){
    metrics.BitSanity[key] = bitDB.test_suites.Where(x => x.id == item.Key)
                                              .Select(x => x.suite_name).FirstOrDefault();
    metrics.BitSanity[Value1] = item.Value1/item.Value2;
    metrics.BitSanity[Value2] = item.Value1 + item.Value2;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply use the `Add()` method.

```
foreach (var item in bitSanityResults)
{
  //It looks like you select a string here. Notice that your Dictionary needs int as key!!!
  int key = bitDB.test_suites.Where(x => x.id == item.Key).Select(x => x.suite_name).FirstOrDefault();

  metrics.Add(key, new[] {item.Value[0]/item.Value[1], item.Value[0]+item.Value[1] });
}
```

I hope this is helpfull. Tell me if I missunderstand your question.

**UPDATE**:

I add some null checks to show you how to fix your NullReference issue:

```
foreach (var item in bitSanityResults)
{
  //It looks like you select a string here. Notice that your Dictionary needs int as key!!!
  int key = bitDB.test_suites.Where(x => x.id == item.Key).Select(x => x.suite_name).FirstOrDefault();

  if (metrics != null &&
      item != null &&
      item.Value[0] != null &&
      item.Value[1] != null)
  {
     metrics.BitSanity.Add(key, new[] {Convert.ToString(item.Value[0]), Convert.ToString(item.Value[1])});
  }
}
```

Comment: @sebi..actually they are of  string type ,I iupdated `public Dictionary<string, string[]> BitSanity { get; set; }` ,how to add string types now?

Comment: @dotnet exactly the same way. :-)

Comment: The exact same way is not working because item.keys and values are of `int` type..I tried as `metrics.BitSanity.Add(key, new[] { item.Value[0].ToString() , item.Value[1] }.ToString());` but it throws an error `No best type found for implicitly-typed array`

Comment: `metrics.BitSanity.Add(key, new string[] { item.Value[0].ToString() , item.Value[1].ToString() });` seems to be working..do you think thats the correct way?

Comment: this is throwing a `NullReferenceException` though,not sure why?item.key and item.values are not null and do have values

Comment: @dotnet oh sorry thought item.values also become string. In this case .ToString(); is correct. Otherwise you can use Convert.ToString(item.Value[0]). I think one of your values in the item array is null. If item.Values[0] is null and you try to call ToString() on it you will fail. Make sure all values are set or use a try catch to handle the Exception.

Comment: I did check that Values[0] and Values[1] haves values in it..what else could be wrong?

Comment: @dotnet See my updated answer. Try this null checks and check if your error still exists. If not delete one check and try again. So long as you find the null item.

Comment: the problem is with metrics.BitSanity which is null

Comment: we should add to metrics.Bitsanity,am using `metrics.BitSanity.Add(key, new string [] { item.Value[0].ToString() , item.Value[1].ToString() });`